# Getting unique ID of echo device

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I built alexa smart home skill for my home assistant and need a unique device id that started my skill but can't find a way to do it. As far as I understand it is possible to do this in cutom skill, but can I pass ID, name or something, NOT user ID in smart home skill to allow me to distinguish in lambda function which device triggered my skill?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The music features are the only ones I know of that return a device ID.